# Where is OCaml's alternative string syntax {|...|} documented?

Tags: syntax, ocaml, string-literals

OCaml's syntax for string literals

```
let s = "..."
```

is explained in the manual at the expected position:

https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/lex.html#s:stringliteral

However, OCaml has an alternative syntax for string literals which is especially handy for regular expressions and multi-line strings:

```
let s = {|...|}
let s = {foo|...|foo}
```

Where is that documented?

Comment: http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/extn.html#sec264

Comment: The syntax will be documented within the main part of the manual starting with 4.08 .

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To answer this question myself, the syntax was originally described in the extensions chapter of the OCaml manual:

- Section: 8.18  Quoted strings
- https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/extn.html#sec264

Thanks to glennsl and octachron for pointing this out.

**Update:** Meanwhile it has been moved to the expected, more visible, places:

- https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/lex.html#sss:stringliterals
- https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/coreexamples.html#s:datatypes